# Как отцентровать карту yandex по нескольким адресам

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Есть массив с адресами. Как расставить точки на Yandex карте и отцентровать по ним? Казалось бы стандартная реализация, но ничего толкового найти не смог. Сам дошел только до неотцентрованного балуна:

```
ymaps.ready(init);

var myMap, myPlacemark;

function init(){
    var cord = 'Санкт-Петербург,Невский 33' // адрес
    myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        zoom: 7
    });

  var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode(cord); // пытаюсь передать переменную
    myGeocoder.then(
        function (res) {
            myMap.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects);

             var adres = result.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('metaDataProperty').getAll(); // записываю координаты в переменную

          myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([adres], { // пытаюсь передать координаты и поставить метку
                  hintContent: 'Спб',
                  balloonContent: 'Культурим'
              });

            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
        },
        function (err) {
            // обработка ошибки
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Кусочек из собственного скрипта, метод `setBounds()`:

```
//это ваша карта <div id="map"> где она появится
myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [55.76, 37.64],
    zoom: 11,
    controls: ["zoomControl", "fullscreenControl"]
});

//создаете точки (несколько штук)
myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([50.76, 36.64], {
    hintContent: "подсказка",
    balloonContent: "контент балуна"
});

//добавляете к карте
myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

//центровка карты по всем точкам
myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds(), {
    checkZoomRange: true,
    zoomMargin: 35
});
```

Читайте про метод [в документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#setBounds):

> `setBounds(bounds[, options])`
>   возвращает Map
>   Позиционирует карту для показа переданного района.

Comment: Не могу понять как этот кусок кода использовать в своем примере.

Comment: @КонстантинКузнецов обновил код, myMap это экземпляр вашей карты, примените к ней метод setBounds() принимающий аргументом  метод getBounds() содержащий ваши точки и это отцентрирует карту. Доки читайте, итить.

Comment: Благодарю за пример! У меня получилось.